# IE8 operation aborted if script is in DIV

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Script/index.php?controller=Front&action=loadJs"></script>
</head><body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Script/index.php?controller=Front&action=load"></script>
</div></body>
```

Hello good people, I'm having problems with this in IE8, this script I got works well until I put it inside DIV containers. I googled the problem (because I'm not a programmer) and found that there are so much talk about this bug of IE but none of the solutions I couldn't apply to my problem, it might just be the easiest thing but whatever I tried didn't help. This is simplified page to show the problem, my script has to be inside DIV but it crashes the IE8 & IE7, please help!

Comment: Could you clarify why your script tag should be in a DIV ?

Comment: Sure, its sort of booking script for customers. I need the script window to be in specific place in my design, if I could run the script outside of DIV and place the result in DIV it would be great, but I don't know how..

Comment: You need to tell us WHAT the script does. If it does a document.write, then it could be in a div. If it does something else we need to see

Comment: Well it is a booking script, like the ones for hotels or so, I didn't write the script myself, I bought it from some software company who apparently has no solution for this error. If you want I can send you a link to it, it works great in FF, Safari, Chrome etc.

Answer (score 0):

To put content in a DIV do something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('id of your DIV');
div.innerHTML = 'content of your div';
```

Comment: Yes, I've found this solution, but as I said, I'm not much of a programmer and I wasn't able to pull it out with this php file that script uses. I tried like this but it doesn't work at all:

    div.innerHTML= '<script src="/Script/index.php?controller=Front&action=load"></script>';

Comment: I googled this solution and as far as I understood, javascript cannot be triggered with innerHTML, so I'm stucked :(